# How does QEMU make itself loaded to a high address?

Tags: linker, qemu

I built a `qemu-x86_64` user-level emulator from [qemu-8.0.5 source code](https://www.qemu.org/download/). When I debug it using `gdb`, I found the `qemu-x86_64` is loaded to a high address(0x555555554000) in memory. The lower memory address is reserved for guest program.

As far as i know, we can specify the base load address of an elf in linker script. I have searched the source code tree, and nor words about linker script neither the address string "0x555555.*" are found.

So how does QEMU make itself loaded to a high address?

Here are commands and outputs in gdb.

```bash
~/qemu-8.0.5/build$ gdb ./qemu-x86_64
/* something not important */
(gdb) starti ./test.elf
Program stopped.
0x00007ffff7dd4090 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) i proc mappings
process 26751
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset  Perms  objfile
      0x555555554000     0x55555572f000   0x1db000        0x0  r-xp   /path/to/qemu-8.0.5/build/qemu-x86_64
      0x55555592e000     0x555555970000    0x42000   0x1da000  rw-p   /path/to/qemu-8.0.5/build/qemu-x86_64
      0x555555970000     0x55555597e000     0xe000        0x0  rw-p   [heap]
      0x7ffff7dd3000     0x7ffff7dfc000    0x29000        0x0  r-xp   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
      0x7ffff7ff7000     0x7ffff7ffa000     0x3000        0x0  r--p   [vvar]
      0x7ffff7ffa000     0x7ffff7ffc000     0x2000        0x0  r-xp   [vdso]
      0x7ffff7ffc000     0x7ffff7ffe000     0x2000    0x29000  rw-p   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
      0x7ffff7ffe000     0x7ffff7fff000     0x1000        0x0  rw-p
      0x7ffffffde000     0x7ffffffff000    0x21000        0x0  rw-p   [stack]
  0xffffffffff600000 0xffffffffff601000     0x1000        0x0  --xp   [vsyscall]
```

Comment: Maybe it's `gdb` doing this rather than `qemu` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how does QEMU make itself loaded to a high address?

It *doesn't*. The address it gets loaded at is the *default* load address for PIE binaries.

You will get the exact same result by running `a.out` built this way:

```
echo "int main() { return 0; }" | gcc -xc - -o a.out -fPIE -pie
```

P.S. If you are on a Ubuntu variant, GCC may be configured to build PIE binaries by default.

Comment: I tried to inspect it by generating a pie elf. The result is exactly the same. Thanks for your 
insightful answer.